# How to color fill a country on a map outline

Tags: windows-phone-7, bing-maps, windows-phone, here-api

Is it possible in Bing or Nokia maps to display a blank map of the world where each country is only outlined by its border, and then fill some countries with a solid color? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can render arbitrary polygons on top of Bing maps, but there's no built in functionality to render regions like provinces, states, counties, etc.  In order to highlight a region you would need to provide all the points of a polygon and overlay it over a region on the map.  Here's a great article that discusses drawing "advanced" polygon shapes with version 7 of the Bing Maps AJAX control.

[“Advanced Shapes” (i.e. Donut Polygons) on Bing Maps](http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2012/05/07/advanced-shapes-i-e-donut-polygons-on-bing-maps/)

A possible duplicate question in regards to Bing maps API

[Bing map - highlight country with a polygon on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883555/bing-map-highlight-country-with-a-polygon-on-hover)

Answer (score 2):

A recent [blog post](http://developer.here.com/news/article?articleId=95955) on `developer.here.com` announced that:

> The [Geocoder API](http://developer.here.com/rest-apis/documentation/geocoder) now supports the retrieval of admin boundary shapes
>   (multi-polygon coordinates) with geocoding results. This feature is
>   available for all countries & territories - in line with the country's
>   depth of coverage.

The [HERE Community Examples on GitHub](http://heremaps.github.io/examples/explorer.html#wkt-parser__region-shape-on-click) offers a web-based example showing this. It is written in JavaScript but should give you the idea.

1. Make *http* request to the REST Geocoder service using the `additionaldata=IncludeShapeLevel,[level],` parameter
2. Parse [Well-known-Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) format (WKT) using a regular expression.
3. Take the coordinates and convert to `Polygon`

Now depending on your situation, on a phone you may prefer to offer **offline** only support - because you know the maps are available directly from the device, so if you know for sure which regions you require it would make sense to pre-load the shapes based on a KML or GeoJSON file. If you don't know beforehand, your app relies on http anyway (or the potential set of locations is arbitrarily large) you may as well just *http* use REST geocoding for the regions you need.

By the way, one advantage of the **online** solution - because the Bing and Nokia Maps both use the same dataset as HERE, you can be certain that any shapes you download will match exactly.